# CookiePolicyOptions how to set from the database

Tags: asp.net-core

I have repository structure...  IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,

```
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies 
            // is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
```

options.CheckConsentNeeded

I wanna set it from the database

```
var culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString();
var checkConsentNeededCookieettings = _unitOfWork.Settings.GetAll().Where(i => i.Language.Culture == culture).FirstOrDefault().CheckConsentNeededCookie;
```

you know that these are services

how to configure it and where it is ?
di ? middleware or override ?

can you give me advice about that? and example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I use same way for CustomIdentityOptions, there is a error that :

InvalidOperationException: ValueFactory attempted to access the Value property of this instance.
System.Lazy.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)

what is the different between IdentityOptions to CookiePolicyOptions

```
services.ConfigureOptions<CustomIdentityOptions>();

internal class CustomIdentityOptions : IPostConfigureOptions<IdentityOptions>
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly ILogger<CustomIdentityOptions> _logger;

        public CustomIdentityOptions(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, ILogger<CustomIdentityOptions> logger)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void PostConfigure(string name, IdentityOptions options)
        { 
            var staticSettings = _unitOfWork.StaticSettings.GetAll().OrderBy(i => i.StaticSettingId).FirstOrDefault();
            options.Lockout = new LockoutOptions
            {
                AllowedForNewUsers = staticSettings.AllowedForNewUsers,
                DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(staticSettings.DefaultLockoutTimeSpanFromMinutes),
                MaxFailedAccessAttempts = staticSettings.MaxFailedAccessAttempts
            };
            options.Password = new PasswordOptions
            {
                RequireDigit = staticSettings.RequireDigit,
                RequiredLength = staticSettings.RequiredLength,
                RequiredUniqueChars = staticSettings.RequiredUniqueChars,
                RequireLowercase = staticSettings.RequireLowercase,
                RequireNonAlphanumeric = staticSettings.RequireNonAlphanumeric,
                RequireUppercase = staticSettings.RequireUppercase
            };
            options.SignIn = new SignInOptions
            {
                RequireConfirmedEmail = staticSettings.RequireConfirmedEmail,
                RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = staticSettings.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `IPostConfigureOptions` for this. Create a class that implements `IPostConfigureOptions<CookiePolicyOptions>`:

```
internal class CookiePolicyPostConfigureOptions : IPostConfigureOptions<CookiePolicyOptions>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public CookiePolicyPostConfigureOptions(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public void PostConfigure(string name, CookiePolicyOptions options)
    {
        // do something with _unitOfWork and set values on `options`
    }
}
```

Then in `Startup`:

```
services.ConfigureOptions<CookiePolicyPostConfigureOptions>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using .NET5, and if your database/repository is injected using the out of the box DI, than you can get the service right from the `httpContext`, so just use a lambda function like this:

```
 services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>( (options) => {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = (context) => {            
            // get repo from DI
            var repo = context.RequestServices.GetService<IRepository>();
            // .. Determine result    
            return repo.GetAll().Where(i => i.Language.Culture == culture).FirstOrDefault().CheckConsentNeededCookie;            
        };
    });
```